# Verilog procedural assignment reg guaranteed to keep value when not assigned?

Tags: verilog

I'm using the following logic in a design:

```vhdl
module flipflip (
   input wire d,
   input wire clk,
   input wire en,
   output reg q
);
always @(posedge clk) begin
   if (en) begin
      q <= d;
   end
end
endmodule
```

However, the behavior I actually want is

```vhdl
module flipflip (
   input wire d,
   input wire clk,
   input wire en,
   output reg q
);
always @(posedge clk) begin
   if (en) begin
      q <= d;
   end else begin
      q <= q;
   end
end
endmodule
```

That is, if the `en` flag isn't asserted the flip flop should just keep it's old value. Are these necessarily equivalent? I.e. do I have to code the 2nd, or can I get away with coding the 1st?

I wasn't able to track this down in the Verilog 2005 standard. Where is this covered?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, they are equivalent.  IEEE Std 1364-2005, section 6.2 *Procedural assignments* states:

> ...procedural assignments put values in variables. The assignment does
>   not have duration; instead, the variable holds the value of the
>   assignment until the next procedural assignment to that variable.

You do not need to use the 2nd code example.

Answer (score 1):

The [IEEE Std1800-2017](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8299595) is the current LRM. Section *6.5 Nets and variables* says:

> Variables can be written by one or more procedural statements,
>   including procedural continuous assignments. The last write determines
>   the value.

So they are equivalent. But there is also a uniform synthesis coding guide that says something like

> A storage device gets inferred whenever you write to a variable in
>   some branches of an always block, but not all, and that variable is
>   read without being written to, or referenced outside that block.

Answer (score 0):

Your two examples are functionally equivalent - the first one is common practice

Comment: Great, I thought so, I just wanted to be sure. Any chance you know where this is discussed in the standard?

Comment: @MattHusz: I added an Answer.